# Whitelisted URLs for Google PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

Is there a whitelist of the URLs that Google PubSub publishers need to contact, in case I wanted to allow these URLs to pass through an HTTP egress filter?

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Cloud Pub/Sub API page](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/) gives details about the URLs used to access each Pub/Sub API via HTTP, which all go via https://pubsub.googleapis.com. The gRPC API (and client libraries) all use the pubsub.googleapis.com:443 endpoint by default.